# How stable should the camshaft frequency be?

Tags: rough-idle, cam-position-sensor

I just got my first oscilloscope ( Hantek 1008C ) and I was looking at the camshaft signal on my 98 Mazda 626 GF 2L.  It uses a two wire sensor.  There is a single bump on the face of the camshaft which passes the sensor once per revolution.  At 750rpm, the cam should be revolving at ***6.25hz***.

So here's a screen shot of the signal:

[image]

I have a few question:

First is it normal to spikes all the time like the ones circled between the signal peaks?

How stable should the frequency of the cam signal be?  I understand that there would be a little bit of variability since every time a piston fires you'll get some acceleration followed by some deceleration, but I'm constantly seeing values ranging from 6hz up 45hz, with occasional jumps as high as 1000hz!

Is that normal?  This car has mildly rough idle, which drops low and gets very bad with loads like AC, high beams or holding the break down in gear.

**EDIT Oct. 15th 2017**

So based on this waveform I pulled from IATN it looks like those little intra-peak spike are really just normal noise:

[image]

That was captured during cranking, so it's slower than my waveform.

I'll have to take some more measurements to resolve the question of the scopes' frequency measurement jumping around. It may just be something with the way I was measuring. Since the scope was set to 100ms per division that whole screen is exactly one second and we see six more or less stable spikes on the screen, which is really what we should be seeing.

Comment: I would bet @Ben could answer this.  Great question.

Comment: what does the manufacturer say the signal should be?

Comment: I'd say it's noise

Comment: Noise - I would agree - what were the connections you made between the signal wires and the oscilloscope probes? Open or shielded - given the environment around an engine then noise is easy to get...

Comment: I agree on the noise point. Which terminal are you testing on, the low or high side? Disconnect the alternator and ignition coil and do a cranking capture. Also, take a capture with like a 1s time base and post it. If you can capture when the frequency goes out of spec at idle as well.

Comment: Also, wow that scope is super cheap ($83) for an 8 channel scope.

Comment: ah, the cam turns half the engine speed not twice. 6.25Hz..

Comment: there doesn't appear to be a time scale on that plot. Id assume the obvious spikes are the signal and the little ones are noise. Your scope probably has some threshold settings to filter the noise and properly calculate the frequency.